# Insert new row inside DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my VB class I have defined this attribute as class variable:

```
Friend WithEvents dgw As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
```

Somewhere in the same class is defined a property:

```
Private Sub mySub(...)
    Dim aDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim aDataSet = New DataSet

    aDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("exec something")
    aDataAdapter.Fill(aDataSet)
    Me.dgw.DataSource = aDataSet.Tables(0)

    ' [PLACEHOLDER]
End Sub
```

This code do its job: data are readed from the database and are inserted inside the grid. Now I would manually add new row inside that grid so I wrote this code in place of `[PLACEHOLDER]`:

```
Dim emptyRow As DataGridViewRow
emptyRow.SetValues(New String() {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"})
Me.dgw.Rows.Insert(2, emptyRow)
```

but nothing happen to the `DataGridView` (i.e. No rows are inserted). What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your datagrid bound to a data source, so then you should be adding rows in that data source

```
Dim drCopy as DataRow
Dim tbl as DataTable = aDataSet.Tables(0)

drCopy=tbl.NewRow()
drCopy.item(0)="a"
drCopy.item(1)="b"
drCopy.item(2)="c"
drCopy.item(3)="d"
drCopy.item(4)="e"

tbl.Rows.Add(drCopy)

Me.dgw.datasource = tbl
```

Comment: Nothing is added to the table :|

Comment: @marianoc84 : it's changed .. try again